# How to integrate Random quote into laravel website

Tags: laravel

I want to integrate random quote from other site (brain quote) into my laravel website,How do I achieve that?
    Thanks

Comment: What have you done so far? What's the problem?

Comment: I am newbie in API so I need to integrate  into my laravel project that so

Comment: What @Hamid was referencing Oboss was you should read the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which you have not done _yet_.

Comment: This question is too broad for SO, and it is likely to be closed unless you edit it and narrow it down to a specific problem you are having.  As already suggested, please check out the guides in the Help Centre for tips on writing good questions and getting good answers.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need integrate any API, BrainyQuote providing [widget](https://www.brainyquote.com/feeds/todays_quote) code.

*To add our 'Today's Quote' feed to your web page via Javascript, simply copy and paste this code into your webpage. It's easy!*

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.brainyquote.com/link/quotebr.js"></script>
    <small><i><a href="com.brainyquote.url.CreatedUrl@6d8f3bfc" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">more Quotes</a></i></small>
```

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 0):

Does BrainyQuote provide any kind of API you can use? If not, you need to **scrape** data from HTML or use widget as hakhiste said. It's not really related with Laravel.

Comment: it would be as a comment instead of an answer!

Comment: Sorry, I don't have enough reputation points to comment others questions :(